# ngnix startup isse ipv4 & ipv6

Tags: nginx, web-server, ipv6, ipv4

I'm trying to get my first nginx server setup, and am having trouble setting up ipv4 and ipv6.

I have this in the top of my config file (it's the only server block in the config file):

```
    server {

            # Listen for requests on these ports 
            listen 80 default;
            listen [::]:80 default_server;
    }
```

And this is the error I get when I try to start ngnix:

```
* Restarting nginx nginx
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For clarification, I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 32bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried to bind to IPv4 twice.

```
        listen 80 default;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
```

By default (on Linux) the second `listen` directive binds to both IPv4 and IPv6, unless you explicitly request that it bind only to IPv6 with the `ipv6only` option.

There are two ways you can resolve this. Choose one (but not both):

1. Delete the first `listen` directive as redundant. The second directive will cover both IPv4 and IPv6 connections via IPv4-mapped IPv6. The only down side to this is that your logs will show IPv4 addresses in mapped form, e.g. `::ffff:203.0.113.25`.
2. Add `ipv6only=on` to the second `listen` directive.

---

Note that as of nginx 1.3.4, `ipv6only=on` is now the default, which makes your original configuration necessary in these later versions. Prior to this, the default was operating system dependent.

Comment: "The second listen directive binds to both IPv4 and IPv6, unless you explicitly request" -- not true; that only happens on Linux, it will never happen on OpenBSD, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You're running Linux?

Might have to do something like this, then:

```
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    listen 80;
```